# Dots Splash Screen RPI 3 version "PIXEL"

Tags: boot, cmdline.txt, pixel

[image: Boot Screen]I'm interested in changing boot splash with dots on new Jessie PIXEL. Achieving the dots boot screen is available by changing the /boot/cmdline.txt file by removing serial console and its speed and changing tty1 console into tty3 console.

Default RPI PIXEL cmdline.txt:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

New RPI PIXEL cmdline.txt:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty3 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash logo.nologo vt.cur_default=1
```

So does anybody know the location of that "gif" of 3-dot animation when ignoring serial console so I could change it?

Comment: Are you thinking of a certain splash screen you saw somewhere? I am not familiar with a certain "3-dot" animation...a lot of OS use dots like M$ and Ubuntu.

Comment: If you are interested in 3-dot animation on default RPI pixel IMG just use the code i provided for cmdline.txt and it will be used on start up :). It exists on RPI PIXEL by default.

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question then/

Comment: My question is where is the location of that set of pictures of gif so I could change it

Answer (score 0):

Try this command: `sudo find / -name "*.gif"` This will give you all the gifs on the system. I doubt there will be that many and you can find which one is the animation for the boot screen.

Comment: I was searching for "splash.png" and found the splash "PIXEL" but that was not what I was looking for. . Now I will search for .png if I can find something but that will take some time :)..."gif" gave no result as expected. Probably it is a set of 3 .png

Comment: Or it could be generated programmatically when, on the kernel command line the `splash` has the value `logo.nologo` - in which case searching for a file is not going to help. 8-P